# jPlayer Cannot read property 'poster' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I have a problem with jplayer what I need to do is I want to play next track automatically when prev track is finished.
I have HTML as:

```
<div class="row-track active" data-track-id="30">
    <div class="row-holder" data-src="url/30">
        <span class="status">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="play-pause no-pjax addTrack audio-element" data-audio="mp3_url" data-waveform="img_url" data-id="30" data-album-id="74" data-title="Usually Suspect" data-artist="Ambient Drama" data-original-title="#7">play/pause
        </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-track active" data-track-id="40">
    <div class="row-holder" data-src="url/40">
        <span class="status">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="play-pause no-pjax addTrack audio-element" data-audio="mp3_url" data-waveform="img_url" data-id="40" data-album-id="74" data-title="Usually Suspect" data-artist="Ambient Drama" data-original-title="#7">play/pause
        </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in jplayer -> `bind($.jPlayer.event.ended`
I have done:

```
 var nextSongId = $("div[data-track-id='"+event.jPlayer.status.media.trackId+"']").
            next().attr('data-track-id');
    var trackOnEnd = inPlaylist(nextSongId);
    demo.play(trackOnEnd);

    in demo.playlist I have an array of object.
    inPlaylist function is as follows:

    function inPlaylist(id) {
      var state = null;
      $.map(demo.playlist, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) {
        if(elementOfArray.trackId == id) {
          state = indexInArray
        }
      });
      return state
    };
```

where status is nothing but the index of the object in an array of object.
In some places it working fine. But in some cases it gives me an error of

> Cannot read property 'poster' of undefined

Comment: Did you check loop? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12463115/2630817

Comment: I have used loop but it plays songs randomly not sequentially and I want to play songs in sequence just one after other suppose I have a divs as:

<div class="row-track active" data-track-id="30">
</div>
<div class="row-track active" data-track-id="31">
</div>
<div class="row-track active" data-track-id="32">
</div>

so it will play always in sequence as 
30, 31, 32